# Switching mp4 embedded subtitles?

Tags: html5-video, mobile-safari, mp4

Seeing that iOS has no plans of fixing its full screen captions problem, I've been forced to embed soft subtitles into my site's mp4s.
The question is, how can I switch languages or disable captioning from a JavaScript control? Basically, how does anyone not using an iOS device on full screen change the captioning? Is there perhaps an HTML5 video hook I can use?